# Redirect old query string urls to new SEO urls

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I had urls like `example.com/?area=new-york`. `area` is a custom taxonomy. I had to change the urls to `example.com/new-york`. I want to do a 301 to new urls if previous urls are accessed. and I want Google to update its index. I have been trying to define a rewrite rule that can accomplish this but I failed. Help needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/). This plugin supports full regular expressions and another interesting redirection functions.

Comment: Can't we just use add_redirect_rule() to accomplish that?